# función para insertar diagonales

Tags: java, android

estoy tratando de hacer en en un `EditText` al escribir números en automático se pongan las famosas diagonales en tiempo real. esto con el fin de que mi cadena de números se vea como una fecha.

sin embargo al escribir en ese EditText tengo el siguiente error:

```
3896-3896/com.u_style E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.u_style, PID: 3896
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0; regionLength=6
at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:588)
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1475)
at com.u_style.MenuActivity$9.beforeTextChanged(MenuActivity.java:803)
at android.widget.TextView.sendBeforeTextChanged(TextView.java:7602)
at android.widget.TextView.access$900(TextView.java:246)
at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.beforeTextChanged(TextView.java:9553)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendBeforeTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:954)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:464)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:121)
at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5727)
at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5538)
at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2650)
at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7673)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1422)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1422)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1422)
at android.widget.ScrollView.dispatchKeyEvent(ScrollView.java:373)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1422)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1422)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1422)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1422)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1422)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1422)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2117)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1548)
at android.app.Dialog.dispatchKeyEvent(Dialog.java:747)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2044)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4022)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3996)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3499)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3632)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3499)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5819)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5799)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5770)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3240)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

y esta es mi función:

```
editTextVenc.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                String texto = editTextVenc.getText().toString().substring(0,6);
                if (texto.length() == 2) {
                    editTextVenc.setText(texto + "/");
                    editTextVenc.setSelection(texto.length() + 1);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
        });
```

espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Prueba implementar mi respuesta, si lo que quieres es agregar simbolos '/' luego de insertar numeros en el EditText para mostrarlos en Formato de fecha. Lo probe y me funciono perfecto, dejame saber cualquier duda o fallo para actualizar la respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás intentando obtener un substring de posiciones no existentes o variables en tu `String` `texto` por lo que te causa la excepción:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0;
>   regionLength=6

Recuerda que `AfterTextChanged` se disparará cada vez que el Texto cambie en el `EditText` o se invoque `.setText` por lo que no siempre tendrás un `String` de 6 o más posiciones a menos que lo valides.

**Si quieres insertar el simbolo '/' cada 2 caracteres, para que parezca en formato de fecha puedes intentar lo siguiente:**

Crea las siguientes variables finales:

```
private final String SYMBOLS = "/";
private final int STRING_LIMIT = 6;
private final int RECPLACEMENT_POSITION = 2;
private final int STRING_LIMIT_WITH_SYMBOLS = 8;
```

Luego en tu `TextWatcher` haz los siguientes cambios:

```
  editTextVenc.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("1234567890/")); // opcional, para que el EditText solo acepte esos caracteres
  editTextVenc.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            String text = s.toString();
            text = text.replaceAll(SYMBOLS, "");
            if (text.length() <= STRING_LIMIT)
            {
                int i = RECPLACEMENT_POSITION;
                while (i < s.toString().length())
                {
                    text = text.replaceAll("^(.{" + i + "})", "$1" + SYMBOLS);
                    i += (RECPLACEMENT_POSITION + SYMBOLS.length());
                }

                if (text.length() > s.toString().length())
                {
                    editTextVenc.setText(text);
                    editTextVenc.setSelection(textView.getText().toString().length());
                }
            }
            else if (s.toString().length() > STRING_LIMIT_WITH_SYMBOLS)
            {
                editTextVenc.setText(s.toString().substring(0, STRING_LIMIT_WITH_SYMBOLS));
                editTextVenc.setSelection(textView.getText().toString().length());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    });
```

La idea es reemplazar todos los simbolos `'/'` cada vez que el texto cambie y luego volver a formar la cadena para darle formato. Para esto se utilizo una expresión regular que identifica cada cuantas posiciones (`REPLACEMENT_POSITION`) va a insertar un símbolo (`SYMBOLS`). Si la posicion en el `String` es valida, entonces se procede a ejecutar el `Regex` para insertar el simbolo. Esto se ejecutara solo si la longitud del texto introducido por el usuario es menor a la cantidad minima establecida o texto sin simbolos (`STRING_LIMIT`). Si el texto en el `TextView` excede el limite establecido o String con todos los simbolos posibles (`STRING_LIMIT_WITH_SYMBOLS`), entonces hacemos que el texto no exceda el limite, tomando el subtring desde la posicion inicial hasta `STRING_LIMIT_WITH_SYMBOLS`. Si quieres que el EditText solo acepte caracteres numericos puedes utilizar un `KeyListener` en tu `EditText`.

**Por ejemplo:**

```
editTextVenc.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("1234567890/"));
```

Comment: Hola andres muchas gracias por tu respuesta, en efecto me ha funcionado muy bien tu solución.

Comment: @ValdemarAllanPoe buena suerte. Solo pense que eso era lo que necesitabas. Cualquier duda estamos aquí, no olvides preguntar. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Como podes ver la Excepción que te da  es `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

esto significa que estas fuera de rango , te recomiendo primero preguntar si te texto tiene los suficientes caracteres para poder hacer lo que le estas pidiendo

```
 editTextVenc.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        if(editTextVenc.getText().toString().lengt >=6){        
        String texto = editTextVenc.getText().toString().substring(0,6);
                if (texto.length() == 2) {
                    editTextVenc.setText(texto + "/");
                    editTextVenc.setSelection(texto.length() + 1);
                }
            }
}
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que hay un mal entendido acerca de como funciona el listener `addTextChangedListener`, el error se produce en esta linea,

```
 String texto = editTextVenc.getText().toString().substring(0,6);
```

cada vez que escribas un caracter se llamara el método e intentará realizar un substring() el problema es que nunca llegaras a poder escribir 6 caracteres antes de que trate de obtener el texto, por esta razón obtendras el error:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0;
>   regionLength=6

Te sugiero realizar el siguiente cambio dentro del método `beforeTextChanged()`:

```
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
       // String texto = editTextVenc.getText().toString().substring(0,6);
        String texto = editTextVenc.getText().toString();

        if(texto.length()>=6){ //Revisa si el texto tiene longitud mayor o igual a 6
            texto = editTextVenc.getText().toString().substring(0,6);
        }

        if (texto.length() == 2) {
            editTextVenc.setText(texto + "/");
            editTextVenc.setSelection(texto.length() + 1);
        }
    }
```

Solo que en este código existe otro detalle, si llamas `editTextVenc.setText(texto + "/");` provocará que se llame nuevamente el mismo método indefinidamente.

Para evitar esto, podrías agregar el código que realizaste pero en el método `onTextChanged()` :

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        // String texto = editTextVenc.getText().toString().substring(0,6);
        String texto = editTextVenc.getText().toString();

        if(texto.length()>=6){ //Revisa si el texto tiene longitud mayor o igual a 6
            texto = editTextVenc.getText().toString().substring(0,6);
        }

        if (texto.length() == 2) {
            editTextVenc.setText(texto + "/");
            editTextVenc.setSelection(texto.length() + 1);
        }
    }
```